# Invariance of supercritical bifurcations under change of variables?

Tags: nonlinear-system, bifurcation

I am confused about one statement in Strogatz's textbook, *Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos*:

> This equation ($\dot{x} = rx - x^3$) is invariant under the change of variables $x\to -x$. (56)

How is this so, since replacing $x$ by $(-x)$ gives $\dot{x} = r(-x) - (-x)^3 = -\dot{x}$? Am I missing something trivial?

Does invariance instead mean that if I let $u = -x$, then $\dot{u} = -\dot{x} = -rx + x^3$, so $\dot{x} = rx - x^3$?

Comment: The given answer is correct, but in your notation, you want to check: 
$$\dot{x} = rx-x^{3} \iff \dot{u} = ru-u^{3}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing $x$ with $-x$ means you replace the $x$ inside the derivative as well, thus for $x := -x$ it is :

$$\dot{(-x)} = r(-x) - (-x)^3 \Leftrightarrow -\dot{x} = -rx + x^3 \Leftrightarrow \dot{x} = rx - x^3 $$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought this type of invariance would be obvious, but then I realized that $\dot{x} = r + x^2$ is not invariant by changing $x$ to $(-x)$.